# Uniform bound on product of Gamma functions in an article by Jerison and Kenig

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds, interpolation-theory

Also asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423745).

I have been trying to read Jerison and Kenig's [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971205) *Unique continuation and absence of positive eigenvalues for Schrödinger operators*, and I am having difficulties understanding how they obtain the following bound on a product of gamma functions.

The constants are defined throughout the paper, but I'm also writing them here for clarity. Let $t>0$ be such that $m-1<t<m$ for an integer $m$, and let $\delta$ denote the distance from $t$ to the nearest integer. Let $\varepsilon \in (0,\delta/2)$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary. Also arbitrary are $\gamma,\eta\in \mathbb{R}$. Finally, fix a dimension $n\geq3$. On page 469, in the proof of Lemma 2.3, they write the following.

> Using Stirling's formula and the functional equation $\Gamma(\zeta)\Gamma(1-\zeta)=\pi/\sin(\pi\zeta)$, it is easy to see that for $0<\varepsilon<\delta/2$ and $\delta$ the distance from $t$ to the nearest integer,
> $$\left|\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}(k-t-i\eta))\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}(n+k+t-\varepsilon-i\gamma+i\eta))}{\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}(n-\varepsilon-i\gamma))\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}(k-t+\varepsilon+i\gamma-i\eta))\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}(n+k+t+i\eta))}\right|\leq Ce^{C|{\gamma}|},$$
> where the constant $C$ depends only on $\delta$ and $n$.

No matter what I try, I cannot seem to get such a bound on $\Gamma$. From Stirling's formula I know that:
$$\Gamma(z)=\sqrt{2\pi}z^{z-1/2}e^{-z}e^{J(z)},\quad \text{Re }z\geq c >0,$$
where $J$ is a bounded function, uniformly bounded away from the imaginary axis (thus the c>0). Following the authors, it seems that I should set $c=\delta/2$, or something that only depends on $\delta$. Clearly the $J(z)$ terms are not problematic (as long as the Stirling formula applies). Also, all the terms of the form $e^{-z}$ are not problematic, since the arguments of all the gamma functions add up (with sign) to
$$e^{\sum_{i=1}^5 \pm z_i}=e^{\tfrac{1}{2}n+\varepsilon +i\gamma},$$
(if my algebra is correct), which gives me the right dependence. What I'm left with are the "ugly" terms of the form $e^{(z-1/2)\text{Log}(z)}$, where the principal branch of the logarithm is chosen.
My question is now two-fold:

- Is there a way to tackle the "ugly" terms with log?
- Is it even possible to apply Stirling's formula, when $(k-t)$ in the first Gamma function above might be less than $\delta/2$? (here the obvious answer is that I should apply the reflection formula, but having been at this problem for this long has made me doubt everything...)

Comment: Btw when you wrote "asked on StackOverflow" my eyebrows shot up, since that is a programming forum. You meant "MathOverflow"

Comment: Ups, yeah. That is what I meant...! Thanks...